# solr 8.5.1 Could not load driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Tags: mysql, solr

i know this question had already been asked but can't handle the problem anyway. On solr 8.5.1, i try to setup mysql to solr and configured everything like that :
add theses lines to my solrconfig.xml

```
     <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/contrib/dataimporthandler-extras/lib" regex=".*\.jar" />
     <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/dist/" regex="solr-dataimporthandler-\d.*\.jar" />
```

My data conf is here : /var/solr/data/testcollection/conf and Solr is installed here : /opt/solr-8.5.1

When i launch my import, don't have any error but only : Requests: 0 , Fetched: 0 , Skipped: 0 , Processed: 0 (my sql request is good).

The log show me this :

```
           Full Import failed:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Could not load driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver Processing Document # 1
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:271)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doFullImport(DataImporter.java:424)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.java:483)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.lambda$runAsync$0(DataImporter.java:466)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
      Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
     org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Could not load driver: 
    com.mysql.jdbc.Driver Processing Document # 1
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:417)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.doFullDump(DocBuilder.java:330)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:233)
... 4 more
  Caused by: org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Could not load driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver Processing Document # 1
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException.wrapAndThrow(DataImportHandlerException.java:69)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.createConnectionFactory(JdbcDataSource.java:159)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.init(JdbcDataSource.java:80)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.getDataSourceInstance(DataImporter.java:397)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.ContextImpl.getDataSource(ContextImpl.java:100)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SqlEntityProcessor.init(SqlEntityProcessor.java:53)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.EntityProcessorWrapper.init(EntityProcessorWrapper.java:77)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:434)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:415)
... 6 more
   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Unable to load com.mysql.jdbc.Driver or org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.loadClass(DocBuilder.java:935)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.createConnectionFactory(JdbcDataSource.java:157)
... 13 more
    Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error loading class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:570)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:501)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.loadClass(DocBuilder.java:926)
... 14 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
at java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(URLClassLoader.java:817)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:554)
... 16 more
```

So basicely i understand the problem but can't know how to solve it as i try several solution by changing the dir. Any help ? Thks

Comment: Do you have the [MySQL Connector/J](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) jar file in your classpath/libdir?

Comment: Yes, i've got this : /root/solr-8.5.1/dist/solr-dataimporthandler-8.5.1.jar + 3 files in /root/solr-8.5.1/contrib/dataimporthandler-extras/lib

Comment: from the download the file should be something like 'mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar'. So look at the link.

Answer (score 1):

create a folder "lib" in `solr.install.dir`

download the jdbc driver from: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

put the jar file inside the lib folder

add this to you solrconfig.xml

```
<lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/lib" regex=".*\.jar" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this configuration in file solrconfig.xml

```
 <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/dist/" regex="mysql-connector-java-.*\.jar" />
```

According to "Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver", you need a jar of mysql-connector at the folder.

Make sure there is such a jar and restart your solr.